How to decide between keeping data within the code or in a database
As an example, we have an entity called Invoice which has bills of purchased services.
public class Invoice
{
    private readonly List<Bill> _serviceBills;

    public string InvoiceId { get; }
    public string CustomerId { get; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection ServiceBills { get => _serviceBills; }
    public decimal GrossAmount { get => _serviceBills.Sum(b => b.Price); }
    public decimal Discount { get; private set; }
    public decimal NetAmount {get => GrossAmount - Discount; }
    // Some other properties

    public void ApplyDiscount(IDiscountScheme discountScheme)
    {
        Discount = discountScheme.CalculateDiscount(_serviceBills);
    }

    // Some other methods
}

If we consider the IDiscountScheme interface, its implementations are free to change based on various schemes. But my question is how to decide where the data which is going to be used in calculating the discount stored. In real world, things like discount schemes are frequently changed by the business and sometimes it could seem like providing the data (hard-coded values) and logic using a implementation of IDiscountScheme can be a good idea. But then we will have to re-release the software or at least one of its components after every minor change in our current discount scheme. Storing data in some kind of database can keep the code from change to some extent until those business policy changes affect schemas and logic again. So, is there a way to decide between these two in real life?

This probably isn't enough for a full answer, but ultimately the answer is "risk analysis". Writing a "rules-engine" that can handle discounts that can be specified in "config data" (whether db, file, or otherwise) does (as you identified) make it easy for business people to change the discounts without needing a new release. But its a lot more difficult to code. How often do these discounts change? Do business people want easy viewership/control over the discounts? Is it worth the extra effort to implement such a system?

The discount data for existing schemes should be able to evolve quickly without depending on development pipeline, because it's a common business operation. If today it's 20% off the most expensive item, tomorrow, it could be 21% or 19%.
Keeping it hard coded, would somehow infringe the open-closed principle, create lots of boring change request for developers, and in many cases require a costly overhead cost (acceptance test + deployment overhead), not to speak of operational costs in case of delays because developers are in holidays. This is only a good choice if you want to milk your cash-cow.
So better keep the discount data, including condition limits, in the database with a reference to the applicable discount scheme. This allows also flexibility, when from time to time marketing comes up with a new and creative discount scheme that would require additional coding. In this case, you'd enrich if needed the database with some additional tables/columns for dealing with the additional scheme without breaking the old ones. The best of both worlds.
Some successful large scale ERPs use for example several (4-6) price scheme tables that are applied according to configurable business rules/priorities by a pricing engine, this allowing major corporations to optimize discounts instantly without involving any developments. Business agility !

In real life you need both.
Usually you will have some generic discounts with dynamically assigned values. eg.

discount one: 20% off if you spend over £50 and shop at store X
discount two:  10% off if you spend over £100 and shop at store Y

Because you have a bunch of discounts with the same pattern, it makes sense to have one class to encapsulate the logic and a table of values to populate the different 10/20% etc
But you might also have a different pattern

discount three : Buy 2 of X and get 1 free

This is too different from the first pattern to make a single class do both using the same table. So you make a seperate class, and possibly a seperate table with the 2, X and 1 in it, so that you can have various buy some number and get some number free.
Also you probably have some very special one off offers

discount four : Buy wonka bars to be entered into the factory tour raffle

You haven't got any similar offers and can't imagine what they might be, so you just hardcode the class with wonka bars and have no dynamic data at all
Generally there are are a bunch of common well understood offer patterns like buy one get one free, discount codes, sales etc where everyone understands how they work and there will be lots of reuse with different values and a bunch of "Manager X has a crazy idea" offers where you just hardcode up the rules and don't worry about the generic case

I've been involved with systems that are very flexible and for the most part they are even more cumbersome and costly to maintain than simply hardcoding logic.
Even if the system is flexible, the logic will still need to be tested as most companies want to avoid having users change things on the fly without any testing.  This is to avoid "users now get 100% off of all orders" type of thing. I thought I put in 10%!!
Developers that would normally be making code changes are instead creating database scripts or editing JSON/XML files for the new logic and rules, which still need to be tested, just like a code change.
In the end, these systems end up costing more than having a few developers making code changes to add new logic.  There is also the artificial construct of doing a coding change.  If you are code releasing every day and have good CICD then it's not a big deal to making a logic change, maybe not in real time, but close to it, since one can release anytime.
In the end, here are some items to consider when adding flexibility:

In addition to your main application, building a robust admin/business console is necessary so that end users can make changes.  This includes checking and testing logic so that a "business" user can make a change and know the impact of a change.  So, this means supporting/building 2 applications, instead of just 1.  Manually updating scripts or JSON/XML files will not lead to any cost savings.   Ensure that flexibility can be done with a "no-developer" touch.  This will be costly up front, but in the long run hopefully business users can add logic without the need of a technical resource.
Really drive out business requirements.   Most business users will say I need to make changes at any time, but drill down and see if that is really necessary.  Most likely that sort of flexibility is not needed but not any change any time type of thing.  Knowing frequency of changes will be key.
Just remember that flexibility is a good thing, but it always comes with a cost, so weigh the effort and cost versus the expected profits.


There is already a mature and completely standard technology that keeps source code and data together in a single central location, and allows for safe, consistent, in-flight alteration of the code and data schema. They are called "database engines".
This would seem to be a prime area of application.
The exact details of the implementation would depend on when and how in the billing process the discount is calculated and applied.
But essentially you would define a new stored procedure to perform the calculation for each specific discount scheme, called by a permanent stored procedure which contains the logic for determining which discount scheme is currently in force and then delegating the calculation to the scheme-specific procedure.
Each time a discount scheme is added or altered, a new specific procedure is created for performing the detailed calculation, then the permanent stored procedure is altered to include the criteria for calling it (for example, a date range during which that scheme remains in force).
Occasionally, the details of old defunct schemes might be purged completely from the engine.
This can all be done while the system remains fully online and under normal load.
